# mysql xampp MariaDB doesn't show all databases

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

First, I want to say that i am a beginner of mysql.
I installed xampp and i'm trying to work out with mysql and i started the mysqld which gives me some errors on Innodb. When I digit show databases; I get returned only 2 databases, the standard, while in phpmyadmin it shows much more databases, more of those was been created by me.
Why?

Comment: Which databases can you see in phpmyadmin and which can you see with `show databases;`?

Comment: In command line i see Information_schema and Test, while in phpmyadmin i see these plus all the others i built before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not logged into MySQL with sufficient privileges to see all the databases.

Comment: Yes, i have just solved it with your solution. I was not logging in with my user but with generic mysql without -u USER -p. Thank you